# PHP error when trying to use password reset plugin in roundcube

Tags: python, roundcube

I've upgrade from roundcube 1.3 to 1.4. I'm having trouble getting the plugin for resetting password working correctly. When I try to reset the password, I get this error in the browser:

`Could not save new password.`

Looking at server logs, I see this error:

`[20-Nov-2021 20:32:31 -0500]: <a7o1n9il> PHP Error: Password plugin: Unable to execute sudo /usr/sbin/chpasswd-wrapper.py in /usr/share/roundcube/plugins/password/drivers/chpasswd.php on line 46 (POST /?_task=settings&_action=plugin.password-save)`

I have temporarily set permissions to 777 on the chpasswd-wrapper.py file to rule out a permissions problem. I have given permission for the `www-data` user to run `chpasswd` in /etc/sudoers.d/90roundcubemail on my debian box per the README with:

```
www-data ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/chpasswd
Defaults:www-data !requiretty
```

When I try to run `chpasswd-wrapper.py` directly from the command line and feed in `someuser:mewpass` to it, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/./chpasswd-wrapper.py", line 29, in <module>
    handle.communicate('%s:%s' % (username, password))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 1119, in communicate
    self._stdin_write(input)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 1068, in _stdin_write
    self.stdin.write(input)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

But I'm not sure if this command can be run from the command line or if it can only be called from the roundcube php file. The `chpasswd-wrapper.py` is called from this php file in roundcube:

```
class rcube_chpasswd_password
{
    public function save($currpass, $newpass, $username)
    {
        $cmd = rcmail::get_instance()->config->get('password_chpasswd_cmd');

        $handle = popen($cmd, "w");
        fwrite($handle, "$username:$newpass\n");

        if (pclose($handle) == 0) {
            return PASSWORD_SUCCESS;
        }

        rcube::raise_error(array(
                'code' => 600,
                'type' => 'php',
                'file' => __FILE__, 'line' => __LINE__,
                'message' => "Password plugin: Unable to execute $cmd"
            ), true, false);

        return PASSWORD_ERROR;
    }
}
```

And here is the wrapper script itself:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import pwd
import subprocess


BLACKLIST = (
    # add blacklisted users here
    #'user1',
)

try:
    username, password = sys.stdin.readline().split(':', 1)
except ValueError:
    sys.exit('Malformed input')

try:
    user = pwd.getpwnam(username)
except KeyError:
    sys.exit('No such user: %s' % username)

if user.pw_uid < 1000:
    sys.exit('Changing the password for user id < 1000 is forbidden')

if username in BLACKLIST:
    sys.exit('Changing password for user %s is forbidden (user blacklisted)' %
             username)

handle = subprocess.Popen('/usr/sbin/chpasswd', stdin = subprocess.PIPE)
handle.communicate('%s:%s' % (username, password))

sys.exit(handle.returncode)
```

**UPDATE:** This is definitely not a permission problem. If I change the wrapper script to this, I get no errors:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import pwd
import subprocess

handle = subprocess.Popen('/usr/sbin/chpasswd', stdin = subprocess.PIPE)
sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: "I'm not familiar with python at all. Not sure how to figure out what's going on with the internals of the python script and how to figure out why it's choking" None of the code that you have shown is Python. The error message somewhat suggests that the code is intended for (*very*) old versions of Python, which handled certain data types differently from the current standard. You should start by trying to read all relevant documentation.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Pasted in same file twice. Will fix.

Comment: And I'm running the latest version of stable debian, bullseye.

Comment: You can solve the "bytes-like" error with one character, by using `(b'%s:%s' % (username, password))` in your `communicate` call, but how do you expect `sudo` to work in a non-interactive environment?

Comment: I'm just doing what the plugin's README is telling me to do. Looking at the plugin's php script, the python wrapper is called with `fwrite($handle, "$username:$newpass\n");`

Comment: This looks like a typical Python 2 code running on Python 3 error.

Comment: I looked into that, but according to github, the code was updated to work with python3. See https://github.com/roundcube/roundcubemail/blob/release-1.4/plugins/password/helpers/chpass-wrapper.py

Comment: OK, this is weird. If I just comment out the line `handle.communicate('%s:%s' % (username, password))` in the python script. Everything works perfectly fine. Can this be possible?

Comment: While commenting out that line works to change the password in roundcbe, the system password is not changed. @TimRoberts  I tried using b'%s:%s' but that did not work either. Still get an error: `TypeError: %b requires a bytes-like object, or an object that implements __bytes__, not 'str'`

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug in the wrapper script.

Changing:

`handle = subprocess.Popen('/usr/sbin/chpasswd', stdin = subprocess.PIPE)`

to:

`handle = subprocess.Popen('/usr/sbin/chpasswd', stdin = subprocess.PIPE, text=True)`

Note the addition of the `text=True` argument to `POpen`. This forces the communicate() method to handle the arguments as strings. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html for more details.

Note: I'm running version 3.9 of python. This broken version of the script may still work with older versions of python as-is but I'm not sure.